Trying to use keras pipeline: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Dense:
I installed keras-ocr from pip and am running this:
import keras_ocr
I get this error here but I've read I can just ignore it:
2024-04-07 01:32:55.323689: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-07 01:32:56.612061: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

I continue with:
pipeline=keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()
and get this crazy error:
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Dense: {'weights': [array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32)]}

Anyone know how I resolve this?  I've tried installing tensorrt.  I'm not deliberately passing anything into pipeline other than the command that everyone has as an example.

I had the same problem, it seems like the keras_ocr package has not been updated for the latest version of tensorflow
I fixed the error by running
pip install tensorflow==2.15


I had the same problem when I was deploying the Keras ocr model on the hugging face space with zero GPU.
I fixed the issue by running the below command.
pip install tensorflow==2.15


For me, I was running tests in ipython3 which was outside of the conda env. Running in just python3 worked as expected.
